# Possible to save data fetched by dispatching an action to a variable before it hits selectors/reducers?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I have data coming to the app from a Rails API and I have control over the shape of the JSON object that is sent. When a Redux action is dispatched, the data received is normalized on the front end before being sent to the store.

-simple enough-

What I am hoping to do is pass to the component that dispatches the acton a copy of the JSON data in its original, non-normalized form as props. This will save the 'de-normalization' process of taking that data from state and getting it into a form that is more useable for rendering in the component.

Any ideas on how/ where this can best be done?

Thanks!

FYI: This is a solution to an issue with relational data in normalized state that I have been trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

A possible (straightforward) solution would be storing the 'de-normalization' version in a dedicated property in the store, your component or other part of your app could take it directly access it from there.

You can store this 'de-normalization' version directly in the reducer after the appropriate action was dispatched.